# cannot connect to localhost:9999 -- Connection refused to localhost

Tags: networking, macos, localhost

I have a server running and that is supposed to emit metrics in 9999. I have configured this setting before starting my server. I have a tool which is monitoring for metrics in the port 9999 in the localhost. I get the following error when the monitoring tool runs.. This was working before i restarted my computer. I have my firewall turned off. Not sure why the behavior is so inconsistent. This is on MacOs.

```
   'Cannot connect to instance localhost:9999 java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: \n\tjava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]' collected 0 metrics
  - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks
```

Comment: Check for SELINUX.

Comment: Maybe the setting was not stored permanently. Check with `netstat -anv | grep LISTEN` to se your open ports, and you can use the second to last column value from the output in `ps -p <number>` to see the name of the process listening on the port.